# how to take user input as dictionary and display its content in python

Tags: python, scripting, python-2.6

i am trying to take user input as dictionary and displaying it on the screen using following code

```
import ast
a = input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
d = ast.literal_eval(a)
print d
but this error is occuring

    File "x.py", line 3, in <module>
    d = ast.literal_eval(a)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ast.py", line 68, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ast.py", line 67, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: post the input you passed.

Comment: input : {'a':1,'b':2}

Comment: put a print a to check the real input given

Comment: i have python 2.6 does it depand upon the version

Comment: Try to use `raw_input()` instead of input also try to `print repr(a)` to see what you are getting as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code check difference.

```
import ast
a = input('Please enter a dictionary:')
d = ast.literal_eval(str(a))
print d
```

Answer (score 3):

Just convert to `raw_input` like this:

```
import ast
a = raw_input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
d = ast.literal_eval(a)
print d
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

**Explanation:**

`input()` is just like doing `eval(raw_input(....))` which at your case transforms the string to dict, `ast.literal_eval()` is expecting a string not a dict.

Also pay attention that at python 3.x there is no `raw_input()` since it's converted to `input()`

You can also refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/1982962)

Answer (score 2):

ast.literal_eval is used to convert string into dict object, from my guess you are inserting {'a':1,'b':1} (dict type) , then trying to use ast.literal_eval on it. It will give error as you are passing dict into function which accepts string) . If you want to take dictionary as string then use "{'a':1,'b':1}"

Code

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
Please enter a dictionary: {'a':1,'b':2}
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    d = ast.literal_eval(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string

>>> a = input("Please enter a dictionary: ")
Please enter a dictionary: "{'a':1,'b':2}"
>>> a
"{'a':1,'b':2}"
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```